# how to split xml root into two branches in the same file based on attribute value of child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, split, transform, transformation

If I have this file

```
<config someAttribute="sA" otherAttribute="oA">
<parameter name="p1" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA">
    Something
</parameter>
<parameter name="p2" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA2">
    Something else
</parameter>
<parameter name="p3" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA3">
    Something more
</parameter>
<parameter name="p4" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA4">
    Yet more 
</parameter>
</config>
```

And I want something like this

```
<configs>
<config someAttribute="sA" otherAttribute="oA">
    <parameter name="p1" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA">
        Something
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p2" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA2">
        Something else
    </parameter>
</config>
<config someAttribute="sA" otherAttribute="oA">
    <parameter name="p3" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA3">
        Something more
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p4" yetAnotherAttribute="yAA4">
        Yet more 
    </parameter>
</config>
</configs>
```

Could you please help me with xslt file? Could you also tell me where I can find some useful resouces for learning xslt (from basic to advanced topics, other than w3schools)?

I have decided to provide more meaninful files

I want to transform this file

```
<config width="100" height="200">
<parameter name="account number" country="UK">
    12345678901234567890123456
</parameter>
<parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
    UK0112
</parameter>
<parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
    john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
</parameter>
<parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
    W1A 1HQ 
</parameter>
</config>
```

Into this file

```
<configs>
<config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
        12345678901234567890123456
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
        UK0112
    </parameter>
</config>
<config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
        john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
        W1A 1HQ 
    </parameter>    
</config>
</configs>
```

Kind regards,
MY

Comment: Could you please explain in "English" how to get from your input to your expected output.

Comment: Yes, could you explain the criteria for which parameters should go in which config? Of you want to just arbitrarily split them down the middle?

Comment: Yes this looks "arbitrarily". I do not get the rule.

Comment: I want to transform the xml file at the top with the xslt file which I cannot create. As a result of this transformation I want to get the second xml file. The splitting is based on the attribute name, in this example, children with name attribute of p1 and p2 are taken to the first <config> and those with name attribute of p3 or p4 are taken to the second one

Comment: I think it would help if you showed your real data. It would be easy to write a stylesheet for this that gave you problems when you tried to apply it in your situation.

Comment: But (apart from different atrribute names and values my data looks almost exactly like the first file) I think it is not relevant whether you have attribute "p1" or "account number"

Comment: I still do not get the rule. Or is it something like the numeric part of name value is smaller or equal to "2" than first config else second. Or is a fixed  list of names going in each config?

Comment: This is a fixed list of names: e.g. "account number", "client number", "email-address", "postal-code" instead of p1,p2,p3,p4. And assume that i want split them - "account-number" and "client-address" go into the first node and "email-address" "postal-code" go into the second node – I have just edited my question so you can easily see what I am asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be any unifying rule here other than that "account number" and "client number" go in the first group and "email-address" and "postal-code" go in the second, the best I can recommend is this hard-coded approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <configs>
      <xsl:call-template name="Group">
        <xsl:with-param name="children"
                        select="*[@name = 'account number' or
                                  @name = 'client code']" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="Group">
        <xsl:with-param name="children"
                        select="*[@name = 'email-address' or
                                  @name = 'postal-code']" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </configs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Group">
    <xsl:param name="children" />

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$children" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<configs>
  <config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
      12345678901234567890123456
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
      UK0112
    </parameter>
  </config>
  <config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
      john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
      W1A 1HQ
    </parameter>
  </config>
</configs>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to split the items into groups of 2 (or any number) depending on their order in the source data, you could do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="2" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <configs>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parameter[position() mod $groupSize = 1]"
                           mode="group" />
    </configs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
    <config>
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="../@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $groupSize]"/>
    </config>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this yields the same result as above.

Comment: Great - thank you very much. BTW - do you know any learning sources (in english). I am completly new to xlst and I will work a lot with it in the nearest future. So - I have to learn it so as not to ask every question on stackoverflow

Comment: @Marcin - take a look at this list of resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online